# Getting data dynamically into LaTeX from a spreadsheet

Tags: import, excel

Is it possible to access to data from spreadsheets (i.e. excel spreadsheets) and include them dynamically into a LaTeX document?

We need to compile each month a lot of factsheets and therefore want to do it dynamically and not just convert the data one time into a useful format. It is important for us to have access to single cells of different spreadsheets in the same LaTeX document.

Already explored exceltex from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156177/include-data-from-libreoffice-calc-or-ms-excel), but we need the solution on windows systems.

Comment: So batch conversion to CSV is out of question?

Comment: You may want to consider `R` in the middle - it works well with spreadsheet files, you can do the extraction and preparation there. It then can produce LaTeX tables.

Comment: @percusse yes i think so because of access to many single values. It may be possible, but it gets messy since the cells needed increases over time (future data points need to be added).

Comment: @vaettchen At the moment it is not crucial to make tables. It is about getting single values out of spreadsheets and insert them in many places in the document. For example i want to have something like this: Last months sharpe ratio was \input{"spreadsheet_xy.xlsx";"Cell_yz"}...

Comment: @SebastianBüchler The last part is possible with CSVs but Excel is a nasty nasty format.

Comment: I have successfully used Python with the `xlrd` Module. In one of the latest copies of the "TeXnische Komödie" you can find the article. If you are no DANTE e.V. member, then a) write me an email and b) consider to join to support TeX/LaTeX :-)

Comment: Yes, what you want is fairly straightforward in `lualatex` if your file is in `csv` format.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is probably long past being needed but for any future users who are looking to do this. I've used PerlTeX to get the values from the .xlsx file and found a very simple solution. All that will have to be called in the LaTeX document is a simple `\getValue{B7}` or whatever cell you want to access.

Things that need to be installed;

- Strawberry Perl
- Spreadsheet::Read module (Perl)
- Spreadsheet::XLSX module (Perl)
- PerlTex (You can do this through the MikTex package manager (or whatever compiler you're using))

Okay, once you've done that you can simply add the function within your LaTeX docuemnt

```
\perlnewcommand{\getValue}[1]{

#use Text::Template;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

$data = ReadData ("FileName.xlsx");

$Output = $data->[1]{$_[0]}; #Where the [1] is the sheet, not the input

return $Output

}
```

You'll need to compile the document with perltex but that's not too hard. I've set up a simple batch file that does it all for me.

```
perltex --nosafe --latex=pdflatex filename.tex
```

Here is the code anyway if you guys need it.
Feel free to message or comment if you need any help, or I've not provided the right information. I just thought I'd get all this down before I forget to contribute to this thread that has helped me.

Answer (score 6):

Quick and not too dirty version inspired by @Alex's idea.

Template document:

```
\documentclass\{article\}

\begin\{document\}
Cell B2 from Book1.xlsx has contents {$workbook1B2},
while Cell A1 from Book2.xlsx has contents {$workbook2A1}.
\end\{document\}
```

Perl script (tested on [Strawberry Perl for Windows](http://strawberryperl.com), after installing the [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Text-Template-1.46/lib/Text/Template.pm), [Spreadsheet::Read](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm), and [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) modules from CPAN):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Text::Template;

my $workbook1 = ReadData ("Book1.xlsx");
my $workbook1B2 = $workbook1->[1]{B2};

my $workbook2 = ReadData ("Book2.xlsx");
my $workbook2A1 = $workbook2->[1]{A1};

my $template = Text::Template->new(SOURCE => 'form.tmpl')
    or die "Couldn't construct template: $Text::Template::ERROR";

my %vars = (workbook1B2 => $workbook1B2,
            workbook2A1 => $workbook2A1,
            );

my $result = $template->fill_in(HASH => \%vars);

if (defined $result) { print $result }
    else { die "Couldn't fill in template: $Text::Template::ERROR" }
```

Contents of the two spreadsheets book1.xlsx and book2.xlsx, respectively:

[image]
[image]

Result:

```
C:\Users\renfro\Desktop>perl excel.pl
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Cell B2 from Book1.xlsx has contents 3,
while Cell A1 from Book2.xlsx has contents Column A.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. Perl rules ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look on the package `pgfplotstable` which is part of the famous `pgfplots`. Here is the link to the `CTAN` page:

- [pgfplotstable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable)
- [pgfplotstable documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc)

It is very powerful and can import `csv` files (basically text files) and also process the data (like adding columns and so on).

**But** I think you will have to convert your Excel files into `csv` files by some mechanism (e. g. Visual Basic or the `save as...` function of Excel) since the `xls` or `xlsx` format is not suitable to be read by LaTeX directly. In addition, an Excel document normally has formulas and dynamic data / calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I already took a look at pgfplotstable. My concerns are mainly that you cannot access single values out of the spreadsheets. We need to do that dozens of times for each factsheet. Also converting the excel files each time into a csv is not that convenient since we have a lot of input files.

Comment: Please show an example. Otherwise this is better as a comment

Answer (score 5):

I've used three solutions for such tasks:

1. The [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool) package, which can import and format data in text files.
2. Perl scripts, in particular [template toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/). This is a very powerful template language, which can harness the full power of Perl's database interface. Reading Excel files should also be possible.
3. Since the question seems to be about `.xlsx` files (which are zipped `.xml` files), my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120280) may also help: use [`xslt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations) to process the `xml` into `tex`.

Comment: Please show an example. Guiding the user is certainly useful but still doesn't add anything other than a google search and getting equally confused.

Comment: @percusse I'll look for examples and post them later...

Comment: `datatool` can be used with [datatooltk](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) which can fetch data from Excel files. The only examples I can think of are in my new LaTeX book, which is still a work in progress but there's a [draft version available](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/admin-report-draft.pdf) for the curious.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Nice, I didn't know this new GUI tool.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am so sorry to ask this basic question, but I am new to `datatool` and totally lost in its manual. If I have an external `.csv` file how to read certain cell knowing its row and column numbers in a straightforward manner the same way done by `go to` in excel?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I don't know much about excel, but I'm guessing you're looking for something like `\DTLgetvalue`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Many thanks for considering my primitive question.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am sorry, but is it possible for `datatool` to read normal excel files `.xlsx` or not?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Not directly. You need to use `datatooltk` to convert from `.xlsx` to TeX code that `datatooltk` can read. See [Sample XLS File](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/samplexls.shtml) and [Loading data from a .dbtex file](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/loaddbfile.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on my answer at [Reading datafile entry by entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102591/reading-datafile-entry-by-entry/102619#102619), except that the logic has been put into the `readarray` package.

**REVISED ANSWER**

The revised `readarray` package provides a more natural syntax than shown in the ORIGINAL ANSWER below.  Additionally, it allows a user-specifiable data-separator character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataA.txt}
  .15, 12,   13, 14
  .20, 22,   23, 24
  .25, 45.6, 33, Ending
\end{filecontents*}
\def\dataB{%
B.15 B12 B13 B14
B.20 B22 B23 B24
B.25 B32 B33 BEnding
}
\begin{document}
%
% This says to read the variable \dataA, stick it into an "array"
% called arA with a 4-column width
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{dataA.txt}{\dataA}
\readarray\dataA\arA[-,\ncols]
%
\readarraysepchar{ }
\readarray\dataB\arB[-,4]
%
\noindent
The data in the 3,2 position of the dataA file is \arA[3,2]\\
The data in the 3,4 position of dataB is \arB[3,4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (based on deprecated syntax)

It has some limitations, like using a space as an item separator (which I hope to change in a future release), but depending on the structure of your data, it could suffice.  The important commands are `readdef{file}{token}` to place the contents of a file into a `\def`, `\readArrayij{token}{arrayname}{width}` to read a token's contents into a array, and `\Arrayij{arrayname}{row}{column}` to regurgitate a data entry of the array (with error checking).

If one saves the Excel spreadsheet as a text file, and if the data entries are without internal spaces, then this approach would suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{dataA.txt}
  .15 12   13 14
  .20 22   23 24
  .25 45.6 33 Ending
\end{filecontents*}
\readdef{dataA.txt}{\dataA}
\def\dataB{%
B.15 B12 B13 B14
B.20 B22 B23 B24
B.25 B32 B33 BEnding
}
%
% This says to read the variable \dataA, stick it into an "array"
% called arA with a 4-column width
\readArrayij{\dataA}{arA}{4}
\readArrayij{\dataB}{arB}{4}
\noindent
The data in the 3,2 position of the dataA file is \Arrayij{arA}{3}{2}\\
The data in the 3,4 position of dataB is \Arrayij{arB}{3}{4}
\end{document}
```