# Plot excel file using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm looking to plot an excel workbook on LaTeX using `pgfplots`. The link to the workbook is: https://www.mediafire.com/?35z48u7pu5bd3vy 
I want to plot 2 adjacent columns at the same time. Hence in total 5 plots on the same graph.
I tried to work with `\begin{filename}` but it didn't work. I'm new to LaTeX and any kind of help would be appreciated?

Comment: Hi, welcome! I don't know if `pgfplots` can read Excel files, but if you save it as a `.csv` file it shouldn't be a problem, you'd just need to something like `\addplot table[x=xcolumnname,y=ycolumnname] {filename.csv};`

Comment: Maybe one can use the odsfile package to parse the table if you save the excel file as in ods format, but that would be only half of the job since you have to pipe this to pgfplots....

Comment: Welcome! PGFplots, alone, cannot handle `.xls` files, (`.csv` and `.dat` are ok). Alternatively you can use the suggestions in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198026/getting-data-dynamically-into-latex-from-a-spreadsheet) to Import the `.xls` files into Latex, and then figure out a way to handle this to PGFplots (perhaps another question here, but more specific then).

Comment: Did one of the above tips help you to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?