# Perltex Can't Locate Perl Modules

Tags: texlive, windows, perl

I am using Tex Live and Strawberry Perl installation on Windows 10. My ultimate goal was to get LaTeX to retrieve data from a spreadsheet, as shown in this [old response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198026/getting-data-dynamically-into-latex-from-a-spreadsheet). However, at this point I am trying to get Perl code using an additional module to work in `perltex`. When attempting to use a module in `perltex`

```
! Package perltex Error: Can't locate Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm in @INC (you may need to 
install the Excel::Writer::XLSX module) (@INC contains:
 E:/Programmdateien /texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlperl/lib 
 E:/programmdateien/texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlperl/site/lib
 E:/programmdateien/texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlperl/lib) BEGIN failed--compilation 
aborted at (eval 13) line 6.
(perltex)                .
```

The modules are indeed installed properly. I know this because I can run the Perl code just fine with the desired outcome. The issue only occurs when trying to build using `perltex`.

Comment: Try in a local texmf.cnf `TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL = 1`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked! Just before checking this question I had got it working by manually copying the contents of /Strawberry/perl to texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlperl. Does your fix just bypasses whatever I have in the mentioned texlive folder and finds my installation of Perl? If so, that is great because then I won't have to copy over my perl installation everything I install a module. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to a local texmf.cnf

```
TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_TRY_EXTERNAL_PERL = 1
```

From the texmf.cnf documentation:

```
% This variable is specific to Windows.  It must be set to 0 or 1.  The
% default is 0.  Setting it to 1 tells the Windows script wrappers to
% use an already installed Perl interpreter if one is found on the
% search path, in preference to the Perl shipped with TeX Live.  Thus,
% it may be useful if you both (a) installed a full Perl distribution
% for general use, and (b) need to run Perl programs from TL that use
% additional modules we don't provide.  The TL Perl does provide all the
% standard Perl modules.
```