# Importing Excel cells into LaTeX

Tags: python, cell, excel

I'm doing my first project in Latex and I needed to retrieve values from an Excel file. I don't want/need to import the whole file but I need to reference some cells.

I would need to do something like: The weight of this material is [insert value from an excel spreadsheet]

Can someone please explain to me the easiest approach to this situation? (Since by what I researched it seems very unusual I was thinking it might be easier with python...?)

Comment: See [Getting data dynamically into LaTeX from a spreadsheet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198026/5764). Is converting the Excel file to a CSV an option? If so, you can definitely include content from a CSV into LaTeX.

Comment: @Werner it is an option! I tried to follow that thread but to no avail. Maybe I'm doing some rooky mistake

Comment: Can you post a mock CSV that contains your data and show which value(s) you're interested in?

Comment: @Werner I'm not still 100% sure this will be the output byt maybe something like this: https://we.tl/t-KGcDV5KmNt Thanks!