# Color lines in source code that is embedded in LaTeX

Tags: listings, color, highlighting, xml

I am looking for a way to mark some lines in a source code sample that will be integrated into my LaTeX code.

I already found solutions to embed source code and have syntax highlighting like this solution: [Including XML file into LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91298/including-xml-file-into-latex)
But this is not exactly what I need. Imagine a source code file I include (XML, if this may be important in any way) and I only want to highlight lines 14, 15 and a part of line 16. I already thought about putting my code in word or open office writer and mark it there and include a screenshot instread of the code-file but there must be a better solution than this.

Anyone can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [highlight lines in listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/highlight-lines-in-listings)

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I was looking for but I need to color the text of the code line, not the background of the code line :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{XML}{
    language={XML},
    moredelim=**[is][\color{orange}]{@}{@},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=XML]
<Line1>
    <Line2>
    <Line3>
    <Line4>
    <Line5>
    <Line6>
    <Line7>
    <Line8>
    <Line9>
    <Line10>
    <Line11>
    <Line12>
    <Line13>
    @<Line14>
    <Line15>
    <Line16>@
</line17>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Solution pulled from [Highlight text in code listing while also keeping syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/19250#19250).

Comment: If you directly copy and paste the url of a question/answer, it automatically appears the title.

Comment: One downside of this approach is that it forces you to place delimiters in the listing. That's particularly undesirable when `\lstinputlisting` is used.